# What is the difference between gothic purple rose seeds and gothic purple rose seeds plus?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I got five “g. purple rose seeds+” from completing the safari tutorial, which are the ones highlighted in the screenshot below. How are they different from regular “g. purple rose seeds”?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "plus" icon indicates that the sprouts will grow super fast, as in 30 seconds rather than three hours. This is for purposes of tutorial, to show a hastened version of the growth and harvesting game mechanics.